# Access Secret Manager of multiple google cloud projects using google-cloud-secretmanager client library in java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I using GCP Secret manager to store passwords using the **google-cloud-secretmanager** client library (Java). The client library is expecting the service account key (json) file path for a gcp project in environment variable. I am able to do it for single project, but when I try to access Secret manager of multiple GCP projects, I don't know how to set the keys for different projects in environment variable. Need help in setting the keys in environment or is there a way to set it using java code.

I am using this maven dependency

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-secretmanager</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like most Google Cloud services, Google Secret Manager supports cross-project permissions. You can grant your service account access to secrets in other projects by applying the IAM permission to the service account. Even though the service account resides in `project-a`, it can still be given permission to access Secret Manager secrets in `project-b`:

```
gcloud secrets add-iam-policy-binding "my-secret" \
  --project "project-b"
  --member "serviceAccount:my-service-account@project-a.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

As an aside, the client library does not *require* the path to a JSON service account key. It accepts one, but you can provide authentication via multiple paths, including [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) (preferred).

Comment: Thanks. Can I use the same key which I have already generated to access all the projects by applying IAM permissions?

Comment: I added the service account email to the new project and gave access. It worked. Thank you.